# Bash - Until - One variable not working

Tags: bash, travis-ci

I have the following bash script:

```
    completed=0
    started=0
    total=0
    errors=0

    until [[ "$completed" -eq "$started" &&
           "$completed" -eq "$total" &&
           "$total" -eq "$started" &&
           "$completed" -gt 0 &&
           "$started" -gt 0 &&
           "$total" -gt 0 ||
           "$errors" -gt 0 ]]; do

        CHECK=$(mysql -D apps-api -u root -h $VALUE -ss -e "SELECT group_id as id, created as created, sum(completed) as completed, sum(started) as started, sum(error_count) as errors, count(*) as total FROM TestRun GROUP BY group_id ORDER BY created DESC LIMIT 1")
        read id created_date created_time completed started errors total <<< $CHECK
        sleep 5s
        echo "Looping again..."
        echo "Started: $started"
        echo "Completed: $completed"
        echo "Total: $total"
        echo "Errors: $errors"

    done
```

It works perfectly on my local but within Travis CI the `error` never returns a value, any ideas?

Comment: A good start would be to give the script a proper `#!` line like `#!/bin/bash` and put `set -x` after that and inside the loop.

Comment: @arielCo I have set "#!/bin/bash" at the very top. Adding set -x to see what happens, thanks

Comment: What values are you getting for your variables under Travis?

Comment: Found out that id was not being retrieved from the DB so it was pushing all the values up by one. Thanks for the set -x tip.